# Editing a revision comment bounces me to the top of the page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, revisions-list

When I click the new(ish) 'edit comment' link on a revision as a moderator, the page always bounces back up to the top. This is perfectly fine... if I'm at the top of the page.

Otherwise, it's disorienting and I have to scroll down and find the text box.

Can we make the page stay put when the 'edit comment' link/button is clicked?